# Powershell : Search the Subdirectory and copy the file to that directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have been working on a Powershell script from past 2 weeks and I haven't made much progress in that.

So I'm trying to copy a file called version.properties from the root of my gradle project to the Subdirectories like "src/main/resources", "src/main/webapp" and "src/main/application".
If i hard code the path it's working, but im trying to make it generic by finding the directory and copying my file to that directory.

I want my version.properties file to be copied to "resources","webapp" and "application" directory after i run my powershell script.

How can i do it? Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
$SourceDirectory = "Projectroot\version.properties"
$folders = gci $SourceDirectory -Recurse -Directory
$jar = "src/main/resources"
$ear = "src/main/application"
$war = "src/main/webapp"
    
foreach ($folder in Sfolders) {
    if (Test-Path $folder/$jar) {
        write-host "copying to $folder/$jar"
        Copy-Item-Path "{$SourceDirectory}\version.properties" -Destination $folder/$jar -Recurse -Force
    }
    
    elseif (Test-Path $folder/$ear) {
        write-host "copying to $folder/$ear"
        Copy-Item-Path "{$SourceDirectory}\version.properties" -Destination $folder/$ear -Recurse -Force
    }
    
    elseif (Test-Path $folder/$war) {
        write-host "copying to $folder/$war"
        Copy-Item-Path "{$SourceDirectory}\version.properties" -Destination $folder/$war -Recurse -Force
    }
    
    else {
        Write-Host "No such path"
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what do you have in place so far? It's just a case of running `gci` to find that file and three copy commands after that?

Comment: Yes Absolutely correct. I have a gci and after that i run a for loop to look for those folders and if i find that folder i try to copy that file to my desired folder.

Comment: So what is the problem? What does your code look like? As you do have defined folders you want to copy it to just using a relative part to the root of your search or building absolute paths from your root should work?

Comment: That how my code looks. I have added it in the question.

Comment: something looks wrong with your `$Jar`, `$Ear`, and `$War` lines. those look like you intend to define a $Var ... but you don't have any assignment.

Comment: Sorry that is =. I have corrected it

Comment: There are more errors lurking in it. `Sfolders` in the foreach statement, the else `Write-Host` is missing a `"`. If you don't have a good reason to you might also want to use `Write-Output` rather than `Write-Host`. Your definition von `$SourceDirectory` is a relative file path (will mess up copy and ´Get-ChildItem`). Why do you append `$jar` and so on to the path? With your current code you could skip the whole foreach and just use the `Test-Path` to check that `$jar` exists and if so copy your file to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the path structure of a project:

```
#ProjectRoot
#ProjectRoot\version.properties <--- File
#ProjectRoot\src
#ProjectRoot\src\main  
#ProjectRoot\src\main\application
#ProjectRoot\src\main\resources
#ProjectRoot\src\main\webapp
```

The following script will do what you seek.

```
$SourceDirectory = "C:\temp\Projectroot"
$DestinationDirectories = 'resources','application','webapp'

foreach ($I in $DestinationDirectories) {
    $CurrentDest = "$SourceDirectory\src\main\$I"
    if (Test-Path -Path $CurrentDest) {
        Copy-Item -Path "$SourceDirectory\version.properties" -Destination $CurrentDest
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Path not found: $CurrentDest"
    }
}
```

If I didn't get the path structure, please clarify which is it.
I am assuming too that "main" is a static keyword here but if it is not, that script might need to be adjusted to reflect that.

Comment: This helps. Thank you